# Buildroot does not create /dev entries for emmc on am335x custom board

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, beagleboneblack

I have a custom board based on am335x. I am building a buildroot for a minimal root filesystem (minimal by size) : boots off as initramfs. I am able to boot the image but unfortunately there are no /dev/mmcblk0 entry.
I would like to know how to make it create that entry.
The following is some log and data to help.

======================================================================

```
# ls /dev
console             ram14               tty26               tty55
cpu_dma_latency     ram15               tty27               tty56
full                ram2                tty28               tty57
hwrng               ram3                tty29               tty58
i2c-0               ram4                tty3                tty59
i2c-1               ram5                tty30               tty6
input               ram6                tty31               tty60
kmem                ram7                tty32               tty61
kmsg                ram8                tty33               tty62
loop-control        ram9                tty34               tty63
loop0               random              tty35               tty7
loop1               shm                 tty36               tty8
loop2               tty                 tty37               tty9
loop3               tty0                tty38               ttyO0
loop4               tty1                tty39               ttyO1
loop5               tty10               tty4                ttyS0
loop6               tty11               tty40               ttyS1
loop7               tty12               tty41               ttyS2
mem                 tty13               tty42               ttyS3
network_latency     tty14               tty43               ubi_ctrl
network_throughput  tty15               tty44               urandom
null                tty16               tty45               usbmon0
port                tty17               tty46               vcs
psaux               tty18               tty47               vcs1
ptmx                tty19               tty48               vcsa
pts                 tty2                tty49               vcsa1
ram0                tty20               tty5                watchdog
ram1                tty21               tty50               watchdog0
ram10               tty22               tty51               zero
ram11               tty23               tty52
ram12               tty24               tty53
ram13               tty25               tty54
# cat /proc/partitions 
major minor  #blocks  name# cat /proc/devices
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  4 ttyS
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 29 fb
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
128 ptm
136 pts
153 spi
166 ttyACM
180 usb
188 ttyUSB
189 usb_device
226 drm
248 ttySDIO
249 usbmon
250 ttyO
251 watchdog
252 ptp
253 pps
254 rtc

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
259 blkext
  7 loop
  8 sd
 31 mtdblock
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
179 mmc
# cat /etc/fstab 
# <file system> <mount pt>      <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/root       /               ext2    rw,noauto       0       1
proc            /proc           proc    defaults        0       0
devpts          /dev/pts        devpts  defaults,gid=5,mode=620 0       0
tmpfs           /dev/shm        tmpfs   mode=0777       0       0
tmpfs           /tmp            tmpfs   mode=1777       0       0
tmpfs           /run            tmpfs   mode=0755,nosuid,nodev  0       0
sysfs           /sys            sysfs   defaults        0       0
```

==================================================================

It is booting busybox and using devtmpfs which are defaults for buildroot.
If I use TI's minimalfs, it does show /dev/mmcblk0 so the kernel and device tree are ok. How to solve this.

Regards,
Preetam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create this node manually by mknod

```
 mknod [OPTION]... NAME TYPE [MAJOR MINOR]
```

In your case type would be b (block). Major number you may find in sources or use
`cat /proc/devices` the minor number is a partition number.
If this is not the case, try to enable udev in buildroot config.

Comment: I had to recompile buildroot with with mdev instead of detmpfs.